# ListView in <include>

Tags: android, include, android-listview, listadapter

Hello I don't have a code problem, because I still don't have anything on my mind on how to do it. My question is:

I have a `ListView` created on my `Activity` with `ListAdapter` and I want this `Activity` to show new layout with this `ListView` .

Why the same activity?

- Because I want to keep my `OnItemClickListener` and have a fully working list.

Why I want to  list?

- Because I want better `UI` view for my app.

If I call another `Activity` with new layout that contains  that `ListView`, well, `ListView` will be empty because there is no activity to get list contents.

Comment: persumeably that new activity would have the code in it to populate its list just the same as the first one does. Also your question is not very clear. It is hard for us to tell what you are asking.

Answer (score 0):

So... you want the same activity to display different views after a user interaction? Perhaps a [ViewFlipper](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ViewFlipper.html) might help.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are mis-understanding how Android works...

You can have multiple activities with multiple listviews.  The listviews can all use the same layout or they can use different layouts.  They can also each have their own onItemClickListener.

An example from one of my projects:

```
public class BrowseSetups extends ListActivity {
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        mDBHelper = new DBAdapter(this);
        mDBHelper.open(DBAdapter.MAIN_DATABASE_NAME, DBAdapter.MAIN_DATABASE_VERSION);
        setupsCursor = mDBHelper.fetchSearchSetups(find, column);
        this.startManagingCursor(setupsCursor);
        String[] from = new String[] { DBAdapter.SETUP_PART };
        int[] to = new int[] { R.id.ListItem1 };
        SimpleCursorAdapter tools = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this,
            R.layout.listlayout, setupsCursor, from, to);
        setListAdapter(tools);
}
    @Override
    protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
        setupsCursor.moveToPosition(position);
        Intent myIntent = new Intent(BrowseSetups.this, BrowseTools.class);
        BrowseSetups.this.startActivity(myIntent);
    }
}

public class BrowseTools extends ListActivity {
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    mDBHelper = new DBAdapter(this);
    mDBHelper.open(DBAdapter.MAIN_DATABASE_NAME, DBAdapter.MAIN_DATABASE_VERSION);
    toolsCursor = mDBHelper.fetchAllTools();
    this.startManagingCursor(toolsCursor);
    String[] from = new String[] { DBAdapter.TOOL_ROWID,
            DBAdapter.TOOL_DESCRIPTION };
    int[] to = new int[] { R.id.ListItem1, R.id.ListItem2 };
    SimpleCursorAdapter tools = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this,
            R.layout.listlayoutdouble, toolsCursor, from, to);
    setListAdapter(tools);
    }
@Override
protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
    toolsCursor.moveToPosition(position);
    String Tool = "Tool #: " + id;
    String Description = "Description: "
            + toolsCursor.getString(toolsCursor
                    .getColumnIndex(DBAdapter.TOOL_DESCRIPTION));
    String Location = "Location: "
            + toolsCursor.getString(toolsCursor
                    .getColumnIndex(DBAdapter.TOOL_LOCATION));
    AlertDialog locationAlert = new AlertDialog.Builder(this).create();
    locationAlert.setTitle("Tool Information");
    locationAlert.setMessage(Tool + "\n" + Description + "\n" + Location);
    locationAlert.setButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            return;
        }
    });
    locationAlert.show();
}
```

So that's two different activities, with two different lists, using two different listviews, each with their own onListItemClick methods that do completely different things.